# Centos: Gpg Keys not imported, cannot verify repomd.xml for repo

Tags: centos, yum

I have updated CentOS kernel and restarted the local repo server. After that when I run `yum update` on client, I am getting `http://test.local/repos/test-extras/CentOS/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Gpg Keys not imported, cannot verify repomd.xml for repo test-extras`

I am not familer with yum repo server and looking for help to fix this issue. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like your missing the gpg keys for your repo. Have a look inside `/etc/yum.repos.d/<your repo> looks for the line `gpgkey=` and let us know what it says. Keys are imported with; `gpg --import <key>`

Answer (score 0):

It was missing GPG key. After adding GPG key, all worked ok.